# Auto insert rows with repeated data, following two patterns

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have a table that looks like this:

```
| id  | letter | number |
|-----|--------|--------|
| 1   | a      | 1      |
| 2   | b      | 1      |
| 3   | c      | 1      |
| 4   | d      | 1      |
| 5   | a      | 2      |
| 6   | b      | 2      |
| 7   | c      | 2      |
| 8   | d      | 2      |
| 9   | a      | 3      |
| 10  | b      | 3      |
| 11  | c      | 3      |
| 12  | d      | 3      |
|etc..|        |        |
```

I'm trying to make an SQL statement that auto-fills the table following this pattern up to id 456.

So the letters are ABCD ABCD until the sequence ends, and each 'group' of 4 has a number, that should reach 114.

I'm not sure what the best way to tackle this is, any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: The MySQL INSERTs should be called from a scripting language (PHP, Perl, etc), incrementing the values as desired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following sql script to insert the values required into your table:

```
INSERT INTO target (id, letter, `number`)
SELECT rn, col, (rn - 1) % 4 + 1 AS seq
FROM (
SELECT col, @rn := @rn + 1 AS rn 
FROM (
   SELECT 'a' AS col UNION ALL SELECT 'b' UNION ALL
   SELECT 'c' UNION ALL SELECT 'd') AS t
CROSS JOIN (
   SELECT 1 AS x UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
   SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
   SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 ) AS t1
CROSS JOIN (
   SELECT 1 AS x UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
   SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL
   SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 ) AS t2
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rn := 0) AS var  ) AS s
WHERE rn <= 456
```

The above query creates a numbers table of 121 rows using a 11 x 11 cartesian product. These rows are cross joined with in-line table `('a'), ('b'), ('c'), ('d')` to produce a total of 484 rows. The outer query selects just the rows needed, i.e. 456 rows in total.

**Note:** If you want to insert values:

```
id, letter, number
1   'a'     1
2   'b'     1
3   'c'     1
4   'd'     1
5   'a'     2
6   'b'     2
7   'c'     2
8   'd'     2
... etc
```

instead of values:

```
id, letter, number
1   'a'     1
2   'b'     2
3   'c'     3
4   'd'     4
5   'a'     1
6   'b'     2
7   'c'     3
8   'd'     4
... etc
```

then simply replace `(rn - 1) % 4 + 1 AS seq` with `(rn - 1) DIV 4 + 1 AS seq`.

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ff4c18/1)

Comment: I dont think that is the result OP want.   He may want `(a,114)(b,114)(c,114)(d,114)` so  114x4 =456

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Good catch. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you had a numbers table of some sort.  Here is one method using `cross join` and some arithmetic:

```
select (@rn := @rn + 1) as id, l.letter, (n1 + n2*5 + n3*25) as number
from (select 0 as n union all select 1 as n union all select 2 as n union all select 3 union all select 4
     ) n1 cross join
     (select 0 as n union all select 1 as n union all select 2 as n union all select 3 union all select 4
     ) n2 cross join
     (select 0 as n union all select 1 as n union all select 2 as n union all select 3 union all select 4
     ) n3 cross join
     (select 'a' as letter union all select 'b' union all select 'c' union all select 'd'
     ) l cross join
     (select @rn := 0) params
where n1 + n2*5 + n3*25 < 114;
```